# Magento not sending emails - Version 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, email

In some conditions email's are working properly.

1. Email is working on user registration.
2. Reset password etc..

But not working in some cases

1. New order creation
2. Sending emails from the order page in the admin panel.

Is this something related to server, I've tried to log the errors but it is empty.

**Server:** Ubuntu

**Magento Version:** 1.9.1.0

Please suggest if someone had the same issue, I can see someone had the same issue in some other community but no one answered for that question.

Comment: Did you check the Magento / Apache / server mail logs for errors? Did you try the default Magento email templates instead of custom ones?

Comment: @SanderMangel
No error in the log, I've tried spam folder but the mails are not reached there. Also changed the email template but no luck.

Comment: which log did you check? Magento log? Please also check the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to cron jobs, I've followed [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) documentation.

This cron jobs are must for the latest version of Magento (1.9.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can install this extension as well: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

"Just in case".

Regards,
James

Comment: Does this module removes the sending via cronjob in 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

1. The decision to make customer order receipts reliant on a scheduled CRON job is highly questionable. (When I place an order online - I expect an acknowledgement by return, not sometime in the next 5 minutes.)
2. The default file permissions on both CRON.PHP and CRON.SH (which it calls) are both set to NON-executable so will not be run by default.
3. A CRON "php: command not found" error will be generated in a Shared Hosting environment, due to typical security restrictions: See discussion here:
   http://wireflare.com/allow-plesk-cron-jobs-tasks-while-chrooted/
4. I have been able to manually trigger the cron.php script by going to http://"mystore.com"/cron.php but it is inconsistent
5. I've used AOE_Scheduler (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) to monitor and manually trigger the events, but that just confirms the cron.php "heartbeat" is not working.

So, I'm still stuck and the same topic elsewhere isn't really answered.

Any suggestions gratefully receieved, thanks